# Wait for element visible/invisible when testing React with Capybara in headless Firefox?

Tags: selenium, reactjs, capybara, xvfb

I am doing testing for a React app using Capybara, selenium and headless Firefox to run on Jenkins server. I got some problems with verification of visible/invisible elements which didn't happen on normal Firefox in my local. it seems they didn't wait long enough or didn't click on element with Click command. 
Have anyone experienced the same issues? And how to make it works with best practices or tricks? Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if your provided some examples of your tests that are failing and the error messages generated

Comment: Theoretically working with headless good but it is very hard to handle this kind of issues. I most of the time not using headless.